# Cannot retrieve JSON data for the entire jsTree

Tags: json, jstree

I use the json_data plugin of jsTree.

When I call:

```
$("#my_tree").jstree('get_json');
```

the function returns only the JSON data of the currently selected node.

If nothing is selected, then I can get the entire data and that's ok, but if a leaf is selected I only get the JSON part corresponding to the leaf.

What is the way to get always the JSON of the entire jstree?

PS: I don't want to manually deselect the currently selected node. That would be a dirty trick.

Comment: Have you tried passing -1 as a parameter? Should be no different from omitting it, but you never know: `$("#my_tree").jstree('get_json', -1);`

Comment: -1 as node index for root works

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comments I've tried:

```
$("#my_tree").jstree('get_json', -1);
```

and that works just fine.